# Skipping specific parametrized pytests based on failure for specific parameters

Tags: python, testing, pytest, pytest-dependency

I have some parametrized tests

```
def test1():
  #do test1
def test2():
  #do test2
def test3():
  #do test3
```

Each test is parametrized by

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(x)
```

I would like to run these tests against

```
test_data=[1,2,3,4]
```

I have tried using `pytest-depends`

```
@pytest.mark.depends(on=['test1'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize(x)
```

However, I get that all test_2 are skipped if any test_1 fails.
Instead, I would like test_2  for the specific parametrization to be skipped only if test_1 failed for the specific parametrization.

Can this be obtained in pytest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, if you add separate dependencies for each parameter. In your example you could do:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [1, 2, 3 ,4])
def test1(x):
    assert x != 2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [
    pytest.param(1, marks=pytest.mark.depends(on='test1[1]')),
    pytest.param(2, marks=pytest.mark.depends(on='test1[2]')),
    pytest.param(3, marks=pytest.mark.depends(on='test1[3]')),
    pytest.param(4, marks=pytest.mark.depends(on='test1[4]')),
])
def test2(x):
    pass
```

In this case, `test2[2]` will be skipped, because `test1[2]` fails.

If you want to take the test data from a variable or function, or you don't want that much clutter in the `parametrize` decorator, you can also do this in a bit more generic way:

```py
test_data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def data_dependent_on(name):
    return [
        pytest.param(d, marks=pytest.mark.depends(on=f"{name}[" f"{d}]"))
        for d in test_data
    ]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", test_data)
def test1(x):
    assert x != 2

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", data_dependent_on("test2"))
def test2(x):
    assert x != 3

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", data_dependent_on("test3"))
def test3(x):
    pass
```

In this case `test2[2]` will be skipped as before because `test1[2]` fails, `test3[2]` will be skipped because `test2[2]` fails, and `test3[3]` will be skipped because of the failing `test2[3]`.

This of course works only for one argument. If you have more than one argument, as mentioned in the comments, you have to adapt the code accordingly:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y", [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
def test1(x, y):
    assert x != 1

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y", [
    pytest.param(1, 2, marks=pytest.mark.depends(on='test1[1-2]')),
    pytest.param(3, 4, marks=pytest.mark.depends(on='test1[3-4]')),
])
def test2(x, y):
    pass
```

or in the more generic version:

```py
test_data = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

def data_dependent_on(name):
    return [
        pytest.param(d1, d2, marks=pytest.mark.depends(on=f"{name}[" f"{d1}-{d2}]"))
        for (d1, d2) in test_data
    ]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y", test_data)
def test1(x, y):
    assert x != 1

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y", data_dependent_on("test1"))
def test2(x, y):
    pass
```

Comment: it does not work if I value lists of params e.g. test_data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", "y")

Comment: Well, that wasn't what you asked - you have to adapt the code in this case. I added another example to the answer.